# How to open doors?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I tend to stack up alongside the door with my Assault guys and breach. When ready, I press <kbd>V</kbd>, which is the key bound to open doors on the `PC`.

The problem is that the doors only seem to open say 20% of the time. The only reliable way I've found is to mash <kbd>Q</kbd> then <kbd>V</kbd> repeatedly until the door opens. As I've discovered the camera angle seems to be relevant.

Am I missing something? Or is this a bug?

Comment: In my game, I have to click a door to open it - perhaps the location of your mouse pointer matters?

Comment: @agent86 If you right-click, you move. You have to *left* click the door to open it.

Comment: @StrixVaria, ah, apologies.  It's been a little while since I played.  Comment fixed.

Comment: I assumed it was a bug.  V only works a small percentage of the time, so I switched to left-clicking with the mouse.

Comment: its definitely a camera angle bug, I find that repeatedly selecting the unit that's supposed to open the door and hitting v usually works for me

Comment: Exactly @StrixVaria. This is why I switched to using `v`, as I accidentally ran through a door once and got owned.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The position of your mouse cursor does indeed matter, it must be over the active character, the one who is opening the door.  Hover over your assault soldier, hit <kbd>v</kbd> and watch the door silently swing open.